# specifying values for d attribute of path tag in percentage

Tags: html, svg, path

How can I use percentage values for the `d` attribute of a `path` tag?

For example:

```
<path stroke-width="4" d="M1% 10% l100% 0" />
```

does not work.

Since I want to reuse the elements in svg tag on change in svg size, I'm looking for absolute values (in percentage).

Thanks on advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SVG path data only allow dimensionless numbers, period.

If you want to change the size of a path, you will be doing that with `transform` attributes or by establishing a new viewport. For example, you could wrap your path with a `<svg>` element inside your outermost `<svg>`:

```
<svg ...>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" x="0" y="10%" width="100%" height="100%">
        <path stroke-width="4" d="M1 10 l100 0" />
    </svg>
</svg>
```

There, you define the path coordinates as absolute values. The inner `<svg>` defines a `viewBox` such that the path spans it to the amount you want. Relative sizing and positioning is then possible with the `x`, `y`, `width` and  `height` attribute.

If you want to reuse the same element multiple times, you can do the same with `<symbol>` (a template that won't be rendered itself) and `<use>` elements referencing it:

```
<svg ...>
    <symbol id="myPath" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
        <path stroke-width="4" d="M1 10 l100 0" />
    </symbol>
    <!-- with relative sizes -->
    <use xlink:href="#myPath" width="100%" height="100%" />
    <!-- with absolute sizes -->
    <use xlink:href="#myPath" width="200" height="160" />
    <!-- using transforms -->
    <use xlink:href="#myPath" transform="translate(50, 0) scale(3.5)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: what if i have <svg height="55px" .. how then viewBox will look like (to use percentage like below)?

Comment: Whatever sits inside the box defined by `viewBox` is fitted into the `<svg>`s width and height - regardless of what units you use for the latter values.